# Linear Transformation defined by a Matrix and Invariant Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I got stuck solving this problem:

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$ be the linear transformation defined by the matrix A in the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, $E=\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

and let $W=\ker(T-3I)$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, Show that there is no $T$ invariant subspace $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that satisfies $\mathbb{R}^3=W \oplus U$

Note: when solving this problem I encountered this problem:

[Direct sum of subspaces of the three dimensional space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632365/direct-sum-of-subspaces-of-the-three-dimensional-space)

Comment: Have you determined ker(T-3I) yet?

Comment: Yes: $ker(T-3I) = span\{e_1\}$ (where $e_1=(1,0,0)$)

Comment: You were right with this

Comment: human sometimes make mistake

Comment: but wait it should be   invariant subspace right?because  kernel span vector and  eigenvector span vector is the same

Comment: http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee363/lectures/inv-sub.pdf

Answer (score 0):

kernel of $ (T-3*I)$  is any vector of the form $(0,x,0)$ which is spanned by $A=(0,1,0)$ is not it?

Edited:
we we have like this

A=[3 1 0;0 3 0;0 0 2]

A =

```
 3     1     0
 0     3     0
 0     0     2
```

and we have done
A-3*eye(3)

ans =

```
 0     1     0
 0     0     0
 0     0    -1
```

where

eye(3)

ans =

```
 1     0     0
 0     1     0
 0     0     1
```

clearly this matrix

A-3*eye(3)

ans =

```
 0     1     0
 0     0     0
 0     0    -1
```

has solution

$0*x_1+1*x_2+0*x_3=0$

$0*x_1+0*x_2+0*x_3=0$

$0*x_1+0*x_2+(-1)*x_3=0$

we  get

$x_3=0$

$x_2=0$

$x_1=k$

yes exactly it is spanned by $e_1=(1,0,0)$

we have

Let v be an eigenvector of T, i.e. T v = λv. Then W = span {v} is T invariant. As a consequence of the fundamental theorem of algebra, every linear operator on a complex finite-dimensional vector space with dimension at least 2 has an eigenvector. Therefore every such linear operator has a non-trivial invariant subspace. The fact that the complex numbers are algebraically closed is required here. Comparing with the previous example, one can see that the invariant subspaces of a linear transformation are dependent upon the underlying scalar field of V.

[V D]=eig(A)

V =

```
1.0000   -1.0000         0
     0    0.0000         0
     0         0    1.0000
```

D =

```
 3     0     0
 0     3     0
 0     0     2
```

see please what is output of eigenvalue decomposition

Comment: No. I think JohnSaita determined the kernel correctly

Comment: directly how? i did not understand

Comment: I corrected it - but I just saw, that the y - coordinate can also be arbitrary, so it's not correct. hang on

Comment: Sorry. The kernel you determined is correct

Comment: sorry @Bernd  see please update

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Solving the equation system above I changed rows 2 and 3 which mixed me up. Sorry again.